# ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow with CPU support with CUDA Toolkit v9.0 and cuDNNv7.1 and Python 3.6 in Conda enviroment.

I followed the instructions described in TensorFlow website, and when I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
        return importlib.import_module(mname)
      File "C:\Users\31121\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
    
    
    Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6):

I have found solution for this  it might be that your cpu doesnt support AVX so I install tensorflow from this custommade repository found on github
link is here

**https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel**

I selected 1.12.0 for py 37 in that folder select py36 folder and cpu folder and download the file within sse2

cpu which doesn support download sse2 whl

Comment: Please don't just provide a link as an asnwer. Use them to backup your solution, not as the actual solution.

Answer (score 3):

**you get the problem when used pip not conda**

the best answer is (it's work 100%):

type following command:
if already install TensorFlow you should reinstall it by the following command:

```
 pip uninstall TensorFlow
```

if not, install it by the following command :

```
 conda install TensorFlow
```

I get this solution from this link below :

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23683#issuecomment-513788003

thank's **@sdmars Tamiris Crepalde** she is helping me to get the solution:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBdtA.png)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to install version 1.14 instead of version 2+ from pip install

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a simple solution** (no conda, no gpu/cpu staff)

Uninstall any version of tensorflow you have already installed.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

install tensorflow 1.15

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

run `python`

then try `import tensorflow`

Comment: It says "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" and provides a series going from 1.13.1 to 2.3.0rc0.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I knew that my CPU (Pentium G4560) does not support AVX, so I changed tensorflow version from 1.6 to 1.5. There is a link for the manual:

https://github.com/rohit-patel/Install_Instructions-Win10-Deeplearning-Keras-Tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I have a computer with an Intel Celeron J3455 and I discovered thath my CPU doesn't support AVX, so I can't use official binaries from TensorFlow 1.6 included.

As [ABHAY KOTAL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017830/3549317) proposes, you can use a unofficial wheel that you can find in the following repository: https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

In my case, I choosed Tensorflow 1.15 for Python 3.7 (`py37`): [`tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/raw/master/1.15.0/py37/CPU%2BGPU/cuda101cudnn76sse2/tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl). If you want another version, download an avaliable `sse2` version.

To install the new TensorFlow:

```
pip install tensorflow-1.15.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Remember to uninstall before the previous TensorFlow version installed:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow tensorboard tensorboard-plugin-wit tensorflow-estimator tensorflow-tensorboard
```

Answer (score 0):

found this solution on another thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23683

People, I have solved my problem taking another path. I uninstalled the TensorFlow package that I installed using pip and reinstall using "conda install TensorFlow" and it worked! Now I can import TensorFlow without problems. Hope this can help you guys too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I realized my cpu didn't support AVX. I downgraded tensorflow to 1.5 and it worked like a charm

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

if not you can also try installing tensorflow from source
 [here](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) in case your cpu doesn't support AVX either.