# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal:A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

After installing tensorflow when i import tensorflow getting this error
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal:A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Details -----

tf-cpu version 2.2.0
python version 3.8.3

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932993/importerror-dll-load-failed-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routin. They say you should install TF version 1.15.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us some more details about your problem, the error messages, version you are using, your CPU type etc.?

Comment: There is an ['official' post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso/51606627) on this issue, in which I had provided a [general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011070/on-windows-running-import-tensorflow-generates-no-module-named-pywrap-tenso/51606627#51606627).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using conda (or any other package management system)? If so, did you install your tensorflow using `conda install tensorFlow` or `pip install tensorflow`?

if you installed it with `pip`, I recommend you to uninstall it and then install tensroflow from `conda`. This should solve this.

Answer (score 0):

you may have an issue with CPU AVX compatibility. Check out this thread at GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39423.

Try installing TF version = 2.3.0. If still fails - I suggest reopening that issue at GH.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these steps

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and

```
pip install --user tensorflow --force-reinstall --user
```