# can't import tensorflow in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

whenever trying to import deep learning library like tensorflow, keras show error

```py
import tensorflow
```

```sh
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-370f0fe8bb94> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gokul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

While searching for your issue, I found the following:

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23683
2. [ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932993/importerror-dll-load-failed-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routin)

In my opinion, uninstall tensorflow, if you have installed it using `pip` and reinstall using `conda`.

```sh
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

Modify to `tensorflow-gpu` in case you need that, and before executing above command, make sure you have created a fresh environment in `conda`. Do not install in **base**!