# tensor flow ddl module error being shown even after reinstalling

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, cvzone

I keep getting this `error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\essam\Desktop\break\gear\mouse_tracking.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 10, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import mediapipe.tasks.python as tasks
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import audio
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\audio\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import mediapipe.tasks.python.audio.audio_classifier
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\audio\audio_classifier.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mediapipe.tasks.python.audio.core import base_audio_task_api
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\audio\core\base_audio_task_api.py", line 25, in <module>
    from mediapipe.tasks.python.core.optional_dependencies import doc_controls
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\tasks\python\core\optional_dependencies.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.tools.docs import doc_controls
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
  File "C:\Users\essam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I tried `pip uninstall tensorflow` then installing it again `pip install tensorflow`. I tried updating tensorflow `pip install tensorflow --upgrade` and uninstalling again using `pip uninstall tensorflow tensorboard tensorboard-plugin-wit tensorflow-estimator tensorflow-tensorboard`.

after multiple tries of testing and removing the package and using `import tensorflow as tf` &
`print(tf.version)` to check if the problem is in the code or in tensorflow. I checked [tensorflow install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1) and downloaded  `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).

still got the module `error` after all that so I started searching for solutions online and found these 2 links similar to my issue:

- [ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932993/importerror-dll-load-failed-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routin)
- https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-internal-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-failed/17179

but they ultimately did not help, I'm starting to think I should just uninstall and reinstall everything since this isn't the only package error I'm getting. I'm also having issues with `openpyxl`, I installed it using pip yet its not getting recognized. "openpyxl" is not accessed Pylance, could not be resolved from source. how can I fix these problems?

Code:

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import mouse
import threading
import numpy as np
import time

frameR = 100
cam_w, cam_h = 640, 480

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Update camera index as per your system configuration

cap.set(3, cam_w)
cap.set(4, cam_h)
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.9, maxHands=1)

l_delay = 0
r_delay = 0
double_delay = 0

def l_clk_delay():
    global l_delay
    global l_clk_thread
    time.sleep(1)
    l_delay = 0
    l_clk_thread = threading.Thread(target=l_clk_delay)

def r_clk_delay():
    global r_delay
    global r_clk_thread
    time.sleep(1)
    r_delay = 0
    r_clk_thread = threading.Thread(target=r_clk_delay)

def double_clk_delay():
    global double_delay
    global double_clk_thread
    time.sleep(2)
    double_delay = 0
    double_clk_thread = threading.Thread(target=double_clk_delay)

l_clk_thread = threading.Thread(target=l_clk_delay)
r_clk_thread = threading.Thread(target=r_clk_delay)
double_clk_thread = threading.Thread(target=double_clk_delay)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if success:
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
        hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=False)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (frameR, frameR), (cam_w - frameR, cam_h - frameR), (255, 0, 255), 2)
        if hands:
            lmlist = hands[0]['lmList']
            ind_x, ind_y = lmlist[8][0], lmlist[8][1]
            mid_x, mid_y = lmlist[12][0], lmlist[12][1]
            cv2.circle(img, (ind_x, ind_y), 5, (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (mid_x, mid_y), 5, (0, 255, 255), 2)
            fingers = detector.fingersUp(hands[0])

            # Mouse movement
            if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 0 and fingers[0] == 1:
                conv_x = int(np.interp(ind_x, (frameR, cam_w - frameR), (0, 1536)))
                conv_y = int(np.interp(ind_y, (frameR, cam_h - frameR), (0, 864)))
                mouse.move(conv_x, conv_y)
                print(conv_x, conv_y)

            # Mouse Button Clicks
            if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 1 and fingers[0] == 1:
                if abs(ind_x - mid_x) < 25:
                    # Left Click
                    if fingers[4] == 0 and l_delay == 0:
                        mouse.click(button="left")
                        l_delay = 1
                        l_clk_thread.start()
                    # Right Click
                    if fingers[4] == 1 and r_delay == 0:
                        mouse.click(button="right")
                        r_delay = 1
                        r_clk_thread.start()
            # Mouse Scrolling
            if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 1 and fingers[0] == 0 and fingers[4] == 0:
                if abs(ind_x - mid_x) < 25:
                    mouse.wheel(delta=-1)
            if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 1 and fingers[0] == 0 and fingers[4] == 1:
                if abs(ind_x - mid_x) < 25:
                    mouse.wheel(delta=1)

            # Double Mouse Click
            if fingers[1] == 1 and fingers[2] == 0 and fingers[0] == 0 and fingers[4] == 0 and double_delay == 0:
                double_delay = 1
                mouse.double_click(button="left")
                double_clk_thread.start()

        cv2.imshow("Camera Feed", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```